# redirect_uri_mismatch oauth google login artdarek/oAuth-4-laravel

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, laravel-4, google-oauth

Hi I am using the artdarek oauth for google login in laravel.
I have written the route like the following: `Route::get('usersgoogle','logingoogleController@loginwithGoogle');`
I am using the same code shown in the oauth documentaion https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel
(the example for google consumer).

My controller:

```
class logingoogleController extends BaseController {

    public function loginWithGoogle() {

        // get data from input
        $code = Input::get( 'code' );

        // get google service
        $googleService = OAuth::consumer( 'Google' );
        //echo $googleService;
        // check if code is valid

        // if code is provided get user data and sign in
        if ( !empty( $code ) ) {

            // This was a callback request from google, get the token
            $token = $googleService->requestAccessToken( $code );

            // Send a request with it
            $result = json_decode( $googleService->request( 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true );

            $message = 'Your unique Google user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
            echo $message. "<br/>";

            //Var_dump
            //display whole array().
            dd($result);

        }
        // if not ask for permission first
        else {
            // get googleService authorization
            $url = $googleService->getAuthorizationUri();

            // return to google login url
            return Redirect::to( (string)$url );
            //echo "Hi";
        }
    }

}
```

Now in the google developers I have created a project,created a client id and have specified the redirect uri like the following: http://domainname.com/usersgoogle I have tried with http://domainname.com/usersgoogle/ -'/' at the last but every time its showing me redirect_uri_mismatch error. Can any one tell me what is the right way to do it? what I am doing wrong here?

My google console is like the following:
[image]

Please help. Thanks in advanced...

Comment: were you able to find a solution to your problem? you mentioned nothing about the config, maybe that's the problem.

Comment: config I have used the same as was mentioned in the documentation.....I have got the problem now...the url what was generating from laravel was not the same as was there defined in google developers console. I am using hybrid auth instead

Comment: try deleting your current client id then create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

$googleService = OAuth::consumer( 'Google' );

with

$googleService = OAuth::consumer( 'Google',REDIRECT URIS );

REDIRECT URIS given from your clientID

Comment: even use Artdarek\OAuth\Facade\OAuth::consumer('Google',REDIRECT URIS ) as mine OAuth::consumer() is not working